# Override dynamic CSS in Django

Tags: python, html, css, django

I'm working on a custom Django project and can't get the CSS on the manager webpage to resize an `<input>` form element.

On the page, charfields are rendered as `<input>` and textfields from the are rendered as `<textarea>`s, but when i change the `width: xx` in the css for the `<input>` forms, it defaults back to 16.

Can anyone please tell me a quick way to resize the fields using JavaScript or in the Django framework itself? I've already tried to resize using `widgets = ()` in the manager view file but it had the same result.

I do know all the field sizes are the same for each data type and I do know that the generated HTML for each row in the table is stored in a `BoundField` in a form, in a dict, in a list, before it is printed out, but I'm not sure where the CSS is getting edited.

All I know about that is that `width: auto` in the original CSS before I tried and failed to edit it.

Here's an example of the code I want to edit:

```
table#infos td input[name$="key"]{
    width:14em;
}
```

Comment: It is not quite clear, what do you want. Are you trying to resize a formfield in django admin?

Comment: sorry just realised this site cut out the field names. - I want to resize those fields dynamically depending on how many characters will go in them. for eg if there is no data in the db the field will be 3em but if its 1000 chars it will be 300em long and maybe 10em high as well.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you use a javascript library to do streching of input and textarea field. The best one I've found is Lea Verou's Strechy: https://leaverou.github.io/stretchy/